# Make Django ORM automatically fetch properties

Tags: django, orm, django-queryset

Say I have a Post model like this:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_content = models.CharField()

    @property
    def comment_count(self):
        return self.comments.count()
```

Say I need to get all the data for the post with ID 3. I know that I can retrieve the user along with the post in one query, by doing `Post.objects.select_related('user').get(pk=3)`, allowing me to save a query. However, is there a way to automatically fetch `comment_count` as well?

I know I could use `Post.objects.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments'))` (which will require me to remove the property or change the name of the annotation, as there would be an `AttributeError`), however is it possible to make the ORM do that part automatically, since the property is declared in the model?

Although I could just add the `.annotate`, this can get very tedious when there are multiple properties and foreign keys that need to be fetched on multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not a perfect solution for you but you might find something similar that works. You could add a custom object manager, [see docs](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/mixins.py#L33)

Then you could add a method like `with_comment_count()`. OR if you always want to annotate, then you can [modify the initial queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).

```py
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def with_comment_count(self):
        return self.annotate(
            comment_count=Count('comments')
        )
    # Or this to always annotate
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            comment_count=Count('comments')
        )

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_content = models.CharField()
    objects = PostManager()
```

Then you could query like this.

```py
post = Post.objects.get(pk=1).with_comment_count()
post.comment_count
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped, I answered on a separate post to go into more detail on how I did it but this was definitely the right start.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Felix Eklöf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7088596/felix-ekl%C3%B6f) I managed to get it to work! As specified in the question, this was in the case in which there were multiple properties/foreign keys that need prefetching, and as such the ability to 'chain' prefetching was needed. This isn't possible by chaining `PostManager` methods, since they don't return a `PostManager` but a `QuerySet`, however I came up with a function that caches whatever it is asked to cache all at once, avoiding the need for chaining methods:

```py
class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def caching(self, *args):
        query = self.all()
        if 'views' in args:
            query = query.annotate(view_count=Count('views'))
        if 'comments' in args:
            query = query.annotate(comment_count=Count('comments'))
        if 'user' in args:
            query = query.select_related('user')
        if 'archives' in args:
            query = query.prefetch_related('archives')
        return query

class Post(models.Model):
    objects = PostManager()
    ...

# caching can then be added by doing, this, for instance:
Post.objects.caching('views', 'user', 'archives').get(id=3)
```

Note that for this to work, I also had to change `@property` to [`@cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property), thus allowing the ORM to replace the value, and allow proper caching with the same name.